# Stop creating labels after first click

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I am creating a Marquee Label every time I click on a random Button and set the text of it depending on what case is randomly chosen. Here's my code sample:

```
- (IBAction)randomWatch:(id)sender {
    MarqueeLabel *watchTitle = [[MarqueeLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 77, self.view.frame.size.width-20, 44) rate:50.0f andFadeLength:10.0f];
    watchTitle.numberOfLines = 1;
    watchTitle.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, -1.0);
    watchTitle.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    watchTitle.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.234 green:0.234 blue:0.234 alpha:1.000];
    watchTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    watchTitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Neue-Light" size:25.000];
    watchTitle.marqueeType = MLRightLeft;
    [self.view addSubview:watchTitle];
    watchTut1.hidden = YES;
    watchTut2.hidden = YES;
    watchTut3.hidden = YES;
    watchTut4.hidden = YES;
    int i = rand() % 25;
    switch (i) {
        case 0:
            watchTitle.text = @"";
            watchTitle.text = @" How To Catch a Pokemon";
            [[self watchPlaceholder]loadHTMLString:@"<iframe width=\"300\" height=\"225\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/NyGv8XtKJc4\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>" baseURL:nil];
            break;
        case 1:
            watchTitle.text = @"";
            watchTitle.text = @" Full Turn ECAL/Benjamin Muzzin";
            [[self watchPlaceholder]loadHTMLString:@"<iframe width=\"300\" height=\"225\" src=\"http://player.vimeo.com/video/74735651\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>" baseURL:nil];
            break;
        ........
```

I have 25 cases (not shown all in the code snippet) and every time I press the random button of course that the code will be executed once again creating a new Marquee Label (which is not fine) and change the new label text and video in this case corresponding the new case chosen (this is working properly). My question is how to prevent the label being created once more? If I set up the label in the `-(void)viewDidLoad` in the IBAction the label is not defined so I receive errors everywhere the `watchTitle` is mentioned. I have no clue how to process and any feedback and explanations that could put me on the right track are more than welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the creation code to your viewDidLoad as you tryed (only, put the marquee in a property and hide it). Then on button press you'll just have to show it.

```
//Define the property somewhere in your interface
@property (nonatomic, strong) MarqueeLabel* watchTitle;
//...

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.watchTitle = [[MarqueeLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 77, self.view.frame.size.width-20, 44) rate:50.0f andFadeLength:10.0f];
    self.watchTitle.numberOfLines = 1;
    self.watchTitle.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, -1.0);
    self.watchTitle.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    self.watchTitle.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.234 green:0.234 blue:0.234 alpha:1.000];
    self.watchTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.watchTitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Neue-Light" size:25.000];
    self.watchTitle.marqueeType = MLRightLeft;
    self.watchTitle.hidden = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:self.watchTitle];
}

- (IBAction)randomWatch:(id)sender {
    self.watchTitle.hidden = NO;

    watchTut1.hidden = YES;
    watchTut2.hidden = YES;
    watchTut3.hidden = YES;
    watchTut4.hidden = YES;
    int i = rand() % 25;
    switch (i) {
        case 0:
            self.watchTitle.text = @"";
            self.watchTitle.text = @" How To Catch a Pokemon";
            [[self watchPlaceholder]loadHTMLString:@"<iframe width=\"300\" height=\"225\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/NyGv8XtKJc4\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>" baseURL:nil];
            break;
        case 1:
            self.watchTitle.text = @"";
            self.watchTitle.text = @" Full Turn ECAL/Benjamin Muzzin";
            [[self watchPlaceholder]loadHTMLString:@"<iframe width=\"300\" height=\"225\" src=\"http://player.vimeo.com/video/74735651\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>" baseURL:nil];
            break;
        ........
```

Answer (score 1):

change the `watchTitle` scope into class. Do like this.

```
    - (IBAction)randomWatch:(id)sender 
    {
    if(!watchTitle)
    {
       watchTitle = [[MarqueeLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 77, self.view.frame.size.width-20, 44) rate:50.0f andFadeLength:10.0f];
        watchTitle.numberOfLines = 1;
        watchTitle.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, -1.0);
        watchTitle.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
        watchTitle.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.234 green:0.234 blue:0.234 alpha:1.000];
        watchTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        watchTitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Neue-Light" size:25.000];
        watchTitle.marqueeType = MLRightLeft;
        [self.view addSubview:watchTitle];
        watchTut1.hidden = YES;
        watchTut2.hidden = YES;
        watchTut3.hidden = YES;
        watchTut4.hidden = YES;
        int i = rand() % 25;
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                watchTitle.text = @"";
                watchTitle.text = @" How To Catch a Pokemon";
                [[self watchPlaceholder]loadHTMLString:@"<iframe width=\"300\" height=\"225\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/NyGv8XtKJc4\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>" baseURL:nil];
                break;
            case 1:
                watchTitle.text = @"";
                watchTitle.text = @" Full Turn ECAL/Benjamin Muzzin";
                [[self watchPlaceholder]loadHTMLString:@"<iframe width=\"300\" height=\"225\" src=\"http://player.vimeo.com/video/74735651\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>" baseURL:nil];
                break;
            ........
```

Comment: Nice aproach but I choose the one below because it's suites my needs more.